# How to specify multiple auth in Python's requests module?

Tags: python, authentication, python-requests

I want to access a BASIC auth protected website via a proxy which requires NTLM authentication. I am using Python's requests module to access the website. How can I specify multiple authentication for a request in requests module? i.e. I need to provide NTLM credentials for proxy authentication and BASIC credentials for the original website. I am using the following code:

```
import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth
proxies = {'https': 'https://myproxy.com:8080', 'http': 'http://myproxy.com:8080'}
ntlm_auth = HttpNtlmAuth('ntlm_username','ntlm_secret')
# how to provide the credentials (BASIC auth) required by the actual website?
r = requests.get("https://myprotectedresource.com",auth=ntlm_auth, proxies=proxies)
```

Answer (score 0):

To use HTTP Basic Auth with your proxy, use the `http://user:password@host:port/` syntax:

`proxies = {'http': 'http://user:pass@10.10.1.10:3128/'}`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `HTTPBasicAuth` as follow:

```
import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

proxies = {'https': 'https://myproxy.com:8080', 'http': 'http://myproxy.com:8080'}
auth = (HttpNtlmAuth('ntlm_username','ntlm_secret'), HTTPBasicAuth('user_name', 'user_password'))
r = requests.get("https://myprotectedresource.com",auth=auth, proxies=proxies)
```